# My first ever Android code with Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

As an exercise, I am trying to rewrite the following google tutorial with **Fragment** class. The original tutorial implements tabs by using the old TabActivity class and TabHost/TabWidget annotation.

[Tab Layout Google Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

I have converted all Activity class with Fragment. I couldn't make my new code to work. I think I am stuck.I could not find any 'complete' Tab sample code using Fragment class.

Here are my questions
1. Should I define  in the res/layout/main.xml or calling Actionbar.addTab(...) in my entry class, or both?
2. What would be complete res/layout/main.xml looks like? What would be the root element (i.e. LinearLayout, FrameLayout...etc)?
3. Any additional info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example from the [compatibility library demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/index.html): [`FragmentTabs.java`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html)
and the corresponding layout: [`fragment_tabs.xml`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/res/layout/fragment_tabs.html)

Really, though, I wouldn't start with Tabs if you're trying out Fragments for the first time. Tabs in Android are a little bit of a mess. The above example (from Google itself) uses a hack just to get things working. Tabs just add a layer of unnecessary confusion when you're just learning.

Here's a more straightforward starting-out Fragments example/tutorial: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html
(Just make sure to replace things like `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you're using the compatibility library.)